# Extracting data from database and transferring to interface with Node-red

Tags: php, mysql, node-red

I made an interface with PHP. With Node-red, I'm trying to extract data from MySQL and transfer it to the interface. I fetch data, I can see it in node-red debug. But I can't connect to my local website. Which node I should use for this? Can anyone light me?

I tried MQTT but I'm new to it. I confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is far too vague. We need a lot more detail about exactly what you trying to do, show the code and explain the errors. As it is we really can not help.

Comment: The important question here, is what value is Node-RED adding when you can query the database directly form the PHP?